# How to set function keys as key equivalents programmatically

Tags: xcode, macos, nsmenuitem

**From NSMenuItem Class Reference**

If you want to specify the Backspace key as the key equivalent for a menu item, use a single character string with NSBackspaceCharacter (defined in NSText.h as 0x08) and for the Forward Delete key, use NSDeleteCharacter (defined in NSText.h as 0x7F).

Not sure I understand *"use a single character string with..."* from the class ref.

// This works as expected

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",NSDeleteCharacter];

    [myMenuItem setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:NSCommandKeyMask];

    [myMenuItem setKeyEquivalent:s];
```

[image]

// This doesn't works as expected

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",NSF2FunctionKey];

    [myMenuItem setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:NSCommandKeyMask];

    [myMenuItem setKeyEquivalent:s];
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out myself.

```
   unichar c = NSF2FunctionKey;

    NSString *f2 = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1];

    [mi setKeyEquivalent:f2];
    [mi setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:NSCommandKeyMask];
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In **Swift 3, 4, and 5:**

```swift
let f2Character: Character = Character(UnicodeScalar(NSF2FunctionKey)!)
myMenuItem.keyEquivalent = String(f2Character)
myMenuItem.keyEquivalentModifierMask = []
```

Answer (score 4):

Example for Swift 2.0:

```swift
let key = String(utf16CodeUnits: [unichar(NSBackspaceCharacter)], count: 1) as String
menuItem.keyEquivalentModifierMask = Int(NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask.rawValue)
menuItem.keyEquivalent = key
```